# Can Adventure creatures always be cast from exile?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-adventure-cards

Throne of Eldraine will include 'Adventure' instant and sorcery subtypes, that are attached to a creature (or possibly just permanent) card. The reminder text says *(Then exile this card. You may cast the creature later from exile.)*

[image: Order of Midnight]

Can the creature always be cast from exile (obeying normal rules for casting creatures)? (For instance, if the card was in the graveyard, and then the graveyard was exiled) Or can it only be cast from exile if the card was put into exile by resolving the Adventure?

IE: Does the reminder text serve to remind that creatures attached to Adventure subtypes can be cast from exile, or does resolving an Adventure create an additional effect that allows you to cast the attached creature from exile?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Resolving an Adventure spell puts the card into exile and allows you to cast it from exile. If the card was not put into exile that way, it cannot be cast from exile. The [Throne of Eldraine Mechanics Guide](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/throne-eldraine-mechanics-2019-09-04) says this on the topic:

> Now the fun part of going on an adventure: returning safely! If an exiled card you own is on an adventure, you can cast the creature. This could be the same turn in which you cast the Adventure or on a future turn. **This works only if the Adventure spell resolves and the card remains in exile.** If you cast the Adventure and it's countered, you're out of luck. Of course, you don't have to cast the Adventure at all. You could just cast Beanstalk Giant if you have need of smashing now or you don't want to risk Fertile Footsteps getting countered.

Comment: Yeah, I think maybe the best way to think of this is abilities like we've seen most recently on Thief of Sanity.  The effect that indefinitely put the card into exile is also the thing that allows it to be cast from exile rather than any ability that the card has while in exile.  It is also slightly like Rebound, although that only allows you to cast during the resolution of a specific trigger.